# Certificate is valid, but website shown as not secure on some browsers

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, https

So I'm currently trying to set up a website over https. I have a webserver running Ubuntu and Apache2, and DNS records are set to direct example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) traffic. I have a valid certificate from GoDaddy configured on the website.

When I navigate to the website on Chrome on Windows 10 and 11, the website shows up just fine.  On Google Chrome on Android it works as well. But on Safari on an iPhone, the website shows up as not secure, nor does it work for Chrome on Linux, even though wget on Linux doesn't complain. If I open the actual certificate on any of the machines, all of them are listed as valid. Other websites certified by GoDaddy, such as godaddy.com, work just fine on all machines.

The certificate itself has a CN of example.com, but neither [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) nor example.com work on Safari. My current Apache configuration points to the SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and SSLCertificateChainFile.

Comment: You should give much more detailed information about your certificate, and if possible publish it for us.

Comment: Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for problems. The problem you describe might be caused be an incomplete setup, where  it is properly configured for IPv4 but improperly for IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operating system's certificate store might not consider the certification authority trustworthy, maybe the cipher strength is not enough etc.
These trust evaluations often differ from OS to OS and between different points in time. So looking at the versions of the used software is very important.

Virtual hosters sometimes deliver their own certificate as a second certificate for their server which might cause the SSL connection to fail, despite the customer's certificate being valid and correctly configured.

You can test your server's certificate(s) and SSL setup with [Qualys' SSL server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to find potential configuration issues.

If you want to achieve an A+ rating with a 100 score in each of the domains "Certificate", "Protocol Support", "Key Exchange" and "Cipher Strength", follow these guides from Qualys:

- [SSL and TLS Deployment Best Practices](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-and-TLS-Deployment-Best-Practices)
- [SSL Server Rating Guide](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide)

At the time of writing, [at least 4096 bits of key or DH parameter strength are required for a 100% key exchange score](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#key-exchange) and [at least 256 bits of cipher strength for a 100% cipher strength score](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#cipher-strength).

For an A+ score, [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) with a `max-age` of 6 months or more is required, in addition to a good configuration without warnings](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#changes-in-2009e-21-january-2014).

Comment: I suppose it does help to use something newer than the trusty old openssl x509 command. Thanks! In my case, the grade popped up a B, warning me I had trouble with forward secrecy. I poked around looking for modern sources on forward secrecy in Apache and found [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html) which bumped my grade to an A.

Comment: I added guides for achieving an A+ rating and 100% scores in Qualys' SSL server test.